# Starting httpd: /usr/sbin/httpd: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/libaprutil-1.so.0: undefined symbol: apr_os_uuid_get

Tags: linux, apache, httpd.conf

while starting apache server the following error comes

Starting httpd: /usr/sbin/httpd: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/libaprutil-1.so.0: undefined symbol: apr_os_uuid_get

can you any one help me on this

Thanks
Surya

Answer (score 0):

Installing libaprutil1 worked for me:

```
apt-get install libaprutil1-dev
```